# Excel slow in specific columns

Tags: excel, performance, dropdown

I have a very strange Problem with basic excel functions (Office 365).
If i make a basic list, like:

```
               Price
    January    100
    February   102
    March      105
    April      99
    May        103
```

The months in column A are created by the automatic dropdown of course, then in if i want to type in manually the prices in column B, Excel hangs up for a few seconds after every cell i fill. If I type in the prices in Column C everything works quick and fine. How strange is that? Anyone else discovered a similiar problem? Of course I tried the basic stuff like deleting the worksheet, resaving the workbook etc.

Thanks!

Comment: This is usually due to a calculation occurring somewhere: it could be in a data validation, a formula or a conditional formatting among other things off the top my head.

Comment: Thank you, but there is really not a lot going on a lot in this sheet. Some macros and formulas but the whole workbook is only 370 KB I really don't get it. If I leave one column empty everything works perfectly. And the cells I try to fill in or the ones besides aren't even linked to any formulas or macros

Comment: I also saw that, if I am trying to fill in these "problemetic cells" Excel suddenly starts using over 20% of my CPU, in other cells it just uses like 4% when typing anything

Comment: I'm also going to assume that you cannot share the excel file? Or a dummy of it where the same issue can be observed?

Comment: I copied only the values from every sheet to a new workbook and it works so far (I also copied the makros). I'll let you know if the solution holds over time!